# How to not accept blank and space only raw_input reply in python?

Tags: python-2.7, whitespace

```
newname = 3
while (newname>0):
    Create_Login =raw_input("Create login name: ")
    if Create_Login == (""):
        newname=newname-1
        print "error! Please do not leave it blank"
    elif Create_Login == (" ") or Create_Login == ("  ") or Create_Login == ("   ") or Create_Login == ("    ")  or Create_Login == ("     "):
        newname=newname-1
        print "error! Please do not spam the spacebar!"
    else:
        newname=-2
if newname!=-2:
    #back to menu code and the rest...
```

I have a code like this to create new user in my program, however, for the

```
Create_Login =raw_input("Create login name: ")
```

it accepts any kind of input from user as their username. I want to limit the `Create_Login` to reject invalid input such as

```
[ "", " ", "  ", "   ",...] #and so on
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I think you may want to research regular expressions: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `isspace()`?

`isspace()` checks if the string is just spaces without needing to create a new string object as `strip()` would

```
if(not Create_Login or Create_Login.isspace()):
    print "User has not entered anything"
```

You could also try `strip()`. However like I said before, it would create a new string object.

`strip()` removes the leading and trialling blank spaces. So it will only delete leading and trailing whitespace, no whitespace inside a string.

```
Create_Login = raw_input("Create login name: ")
if not Create_Login.strip():
    print "User has not entered anything"
```

Comment: @HashashihnAltheim No problem, I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for your concern~
Recently, I just found a very useful and simple way to solve this.

```
#by doing .strip
Create_Login = raw_input('new username: ')
Create_Login = str(Create_Login.strip(' '))
```

this new line read Create_login as string and delete all space in it to create a valid username without space.

```
#e.g.: "A  B" = "AB", "   C" = "C", or "  "=""
```

Comment: Mind that `strip()` will only delete leading and trailing whitespace, no whitespace inside a string. So `"A   B".strip(' ')` will result in `"A   B"`, **not** `"AB"`. You may want to use `"".join(x for x in my_string if x != ' ')` for that or something similar.